# postfix, spamassassin user_prefs and aliases

Tags: email, postfix, aliases

I implemented spamassassin mailfiltering in my postfix setup using the 
`-o content_filter=spamassassin` and a transport like this:

```
spamassassin   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
   user=spamassassin argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Next, I would like to implement user-based spamassassin preferences by sql using the `user_prefs` option as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/UsingSQL).

- How is this setup going to handle aliases?
- Is spamassassin going to be called BEFORE alias expansion?
- If this is the case, the whole user based preferences configuration is pretty much ruined. Are there any ways to implement complete user based preferences even with aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated this by creating a wrapper script around sendmail (as it got `${recipient}` as argument anyway).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@" >> /var/log/sendmail-test.log
/usr/sbin/sendmail-orig "$@"
```

This little piece of code actually revealed that aliases seem to be processed before being handed over to spamassassin. Thats great.

Another important thing I noticed while doing this is, that it's important to include a line like this in your main.cf:

```
spamassassin_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

If you don't, `${recipient}` is going to contain multiple users which is going to crash the user based preferences as well.

When having a setup like this, spamc might get called many many times with the same mail but just different user over and over again. This leads to another question: 
[How does spamassassin handle mails with the same content, but just a different recipient?](https://serverfault.com/questions/510958/how-does-spamassassin-handle-mails-with-the-same-content-but-just-a-different-r)